# I keep getting 0 as an answer for my mips code where I'm supposed to find the gcd of two numbers

Tags: mips, greatest-common-divisor

```
.data
    n1:.asciiz"Enter the first number:"
    n2: .asciiz"Enter the second number:"

.text
.globl main
main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,n1
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 5      # get input from user
    syscall
    move $a0,$s0
      
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,n2
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 5      # get second input from user
    syscall
    move $a0,$s1
   
    jal calcGCD # call function calcGCD

    add $a0,$v0,$zero 
    li $v0,1
    syscall # print result
    li $v0, 10 # exit program 
    syscall

calcGCD:
    #GCD(n1, n2)
    # n1 = $a0
    # n2 = $a1

    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp) # save function into stack
    sw $s0, 4($sp) # save value $s0 into stack 
    sw $s1, 8($sp) # save value $s1 into stack 

    add $s0, $a0, $zero # s0 = a0 ( value n1 ) 
    add $s1, $a1, $zero # s1 = a1 ( value n2 ) 

    addi $t1, $zero, 0 # $t1 = 0
    beq $s1, $t1, return # if s1 == 0 return

    add $a0, $zero, $s1 # make a0 = $s1
    div $s0, $s1 # n1/n2
    mfhi $a1 # reminder of n1/n2 which is equal to n1%n2

    jal calcGCD

exitGCD:
    lw $ra, 0 ($sp)  # read registers from stack
    lw $s0, 4 ($sp)
    lw $s1, 8 ($sp)
    addi $sp,$sp , 12 # bring back stack pointer
    jr $ra
return:
    add $v0, $zero, $s0 # return $v0 = $s0 ( n1)
    j exitGCD
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it, say by single stepping and seeing if each line does what you're expecting? If yes, where does it go wrong? If no, why not? Looking at the final output of the program to see if it works or not is not a great debugging approach. Assembly code can go wrong at any instruction with a typo or other problem and you won't find it in the output. (Sending code through the internet is also not a great debugging approach, but does sometimes work.)  Try it on the smallest possible input values and single step to see it works.  When it does try larger inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is with the part where you store the user input in the registers. In move $a0,$s0, you are moving the value at $s0 into $a0 when the user input is stored in $v0, therefore, it should be move $a0,$v0, and from your function, you seem to have stored the second input in $a1 but in your code, both the inputs are being stored in the same register so the next command should be move $a1,$v0. Here is one version of your code.

```
.data
n1:.asciiz"Enter the first number:"
n2: .asciiz"Enter the second number:"

.text
.globl main
main:
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,n1
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 5      # get input from user
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0 #temporarily store the user input in another register because $a0 is having another value stored in it in the next command
      
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,n2
    syscall
    
    li  $v0, 5      # get second input from user
    syscall
    move $a1,$v0
    move $a0,$t0    #transfer the first user input into $a0 to be used in the function
   
    jal calcGCD # call function calcGCD

    add $a0,$v0,$zero 
    li $v0,1
    syscall # print result
    li $v0, 10 # exit program 
    syscall

calcGCD:
    #GCD(n1, n2)
    # n1 = $a0
    # n2 = $a1

    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp) # save function into stack
    sw $s0, 4($sp) # save value $s0 into stack 
    sw $s1, 8($sp) # save value $s1 into stack 

    add $s0, $a0, $zero # s0 = a0 ( value n1 ) 
    add $s1, $a1, $zero # s1 = a1 ( value n2 ) 

    addi $t1, $zero, 0 # $t1 = 0
    beq $s1, $t1, return # if s1 == 0 return

    add $a0, $zero, $s1 # make a0 = $s1
    div $s0, $s1 # n1/n2
    mfhi $a1 # reminder of n1/n2 which is equal to n1%n2

    jal calcGCD

exitGCD:
    lw $ra, 0 ($sp)  # read registers from stack
    lw $s0, 4 ($sp)
    lw $s1, 8 ($sp)
    addi $sp,$sp , 12 # bring back stack pointer
    jr $ra
return:
    add $v0, $zero, $s0 # return $v0 = $s0 ( n1)
    j exitGCD
```